# How can I use spate Ray app for WordPress debug?

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-plugin-creation

I'm using `Local` for WordPress plugin development.

I'm trying to configure the `Ray` app for it. I already installed and activated the `Ray` Desktop app and the `WordPress-ray` plugin for it.

Also this one configured as the documentation `define( 'WP_ENVIRONMENT_TYPE', 'local' );`

This does not work for me.

If `ray("Ray");` is defined in my code, I've got some errors:

```
Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function MH_Slider\ray()
```

How do I configure it properly?

[Docs Link](https://spatie.be/docs/ray/v1/installation-in-your-project/wordpress)

Answer (score 0):

According to your error message `Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function MH_Slider\ray()` it does seem that your problem is related to you improperly calling a function outside your namespace.

The probable solution is to call the function with a backward slash () before. This shows that the `ray()` function is above your namespace.